# Images getting bigger then defined size and out of div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap to create a html page where I am showing a list of images. But some images are showing bigger and the last image sometimes get out of my main container div. Also, if i reduce the browser size then some items overlap at some point. How do I solve it?

My css:

```
* { arial, sans-serif !important;   }

body{  padding-top: 50px;    }

img.img-thumb{
    height: 180px;
    width: auto;    }
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <title>Test Web</title>

</head>


<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- ------------------  Main   ----------------------- -->
        <div class="col-md-2">Left sideBar</div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h2 class="text-center">Mens shoes</h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <h4>shoe-1</h4>
                    <img src="https://cdn.sweatband.com/asics_gel-pulse_11_mens_running_shoes_asics_gel-pulse_11_mens_running_shoes12.jpg"
                        alt="shoe-1" class="img-thumb" />
                    <p class="list-price text-danger">List Price: £50 </p>


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="">Details</button>
                </div>


                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 ">
                    <h4>shoe-1</h4>
                    <img src="https://images.sportsdirect.com/images/products/21113502_l.jpg" alt="shoe-1"
                        class="img-thumb" />
                    <p class="list-price text-danger">List Price: £50 </p>


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="">Details</button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <h4>shoe-1</h4>
                    <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/merrell-nova-mens-0506-1563371874.jpg"
                        alt="shoe-1" class="img-thumb" />
                    <p class="list-price text-danger">List Price: £50 </p>


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="">Details</button>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
                    <h4>shoe-1</h4>
                    <img src="https://absolute-snow.cdn.rlab.net/Larger/6e291399-33da-47c3-97df-3e5712d6c932cloudventure-mens-trail-running-shoes-flare-dawn-p9007-8363_.jpg"
                        alt="shoe-1" class="img-thumb" />
                    <p class="list-price text-danger">List Price: £50 </p>


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick="">Details</button>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>



        <div class="col-md-2">Right sideBar</div>


        <!-- ----------------------- footer ------------------------- -->

    </div>
    <br><br>

    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        &copy; Copyright 2013-2015
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/rashed007/xeukaqr4/1/

One solution I found is that instead of defining image width I can say max-width: 100%;

So, if I use the below code then images loose their ratio :

```
img.img-thumb{
    height: 180px;
    width: auto;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

and if I use the below then the images get into different sizes:

```
 img.img-thumb{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}
```

How to properly do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using BS3 give the images the class `img-responsive` and remove the max-* attributes you added. That's a [built-in BS3 class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#images) that sets the max-width to 100% and the height will adjust automatically based on the intrinsic aspect ratio of your image.

Comment: Thanks. That will solve my problem. But what if I used BS4? and also if my image is of less than 180px then it doesnt resize. How do I resize it too?

Comment: For some reason in BS4 they changes the class from `img-responsive` to `img-fluid` which was a problem for most people although there are some simple workarounds.